# How to make password fields in browsers show plain text?

Tags: browser, passwords

When I'm using the browsers installed on my stationary computer at home, there is no need to conceal the passwords I type in. Instead I'd like to be able to view them as plain text so I don't make any errors while I type.

**Is there any way to enforce this behaviour in the standard web browsers?** I'm particularly interested in Firefox and Chrome, but I think it is equally interesting for Internet Explorer, Opera, Safari and other browsers.

Comment: Just as a nice read (which I do NOT agree on): Jakob Nielsen thinks browsers should stop password masking altogether; http://www.useit.com/alertbox/passwords.html (I do agree website designers should stop using the Reset button though.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Firefox I use the add-on [Unhide Passwords](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/462).

Answer (score 4):

**[Show Password](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10174)** (Firefox Addon)

> If you are not worried about someone
>   looking from behind your back and
>   stealing your passwords, why take
>   additional pain for typing ****
>   password fields, where you dont know
>   whether you typed your long password
>   correctly or not

while there are many [passord revealers](http://www.mydigitallife.co.za/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=10504&Itemid=43) available to show passwords stored with Internet Explorer (or other web browsers) as clear text, (to the best of my knowledge) there is no option to show text instead of asterisks while you type the password.