# In Firefox, how can I make all password input fields show text instead of dots?

Tags: firefox, passwords

This would be great. I would also like to make sure that I can copy the password easily. Sometimes websites disable the good old <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> feature.

I'm not interested in any discussion regarding if this is bad practice.

Comment: By default, web browsers obscure the password data by just using dots instead of characters. Websites that go out of their way to allow for a “show password” option typically have to restructure their code to circumvent that default behavior. Meaning, what you are asking about is really not that easy to override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several add-ons for this purpose. Below are the ones that I've tried

- [Show/hide passwords](https://addons.mozilla.org/vi/firefox/addon/showhide-passwords/)

  [image: Show/hide passwords screenshot]
- [Show Saved Password](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/show-saved-password/)

  [image: Show Saved Password screenshot]
- [Show my Password](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/see-my-passwords/)

  [image: Show my Password screenshot]

You can find more on the [extension store](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?platform=windows&q=show%20password). There are other suggestions in [How to make password fields in browsers show plain text?](https://superuser.com/q/47515/241386)

Comment: Thanks! I guess that add-ons are an option even though I would prefer if this was a setting in Firefox. Or a few lines of script + CSS in some file. At least for plain password inputs, I think there should be a simple solution that does not involve add-ons. Enabling copy of passwords is probably more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

That highly depends on the code websites use. usually the user has no control over this as it’s a standard security feature almost all languages and frameworks strongly recommend or outright force.

Sometimes you can click the “Show Password” box.

All modern browsers offer a feature that can auto fill password boxs, maybe that will help. Or use a password manager or plug-in

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox, there is the [see-password](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/see-password/?src=search) extension that reveals the text in the password box on some sites.

There are also [bookmarklets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) (small JavaScript files) such as [View Password](https://ostermiller.org/bookmarklets/password.html) that provide limited ability to view passwords, i.e. showing what was by clicking the bookmarklet. Again, these may not work on all sites.